# View gif animations on bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

On my **bq Aquaris M10 Ubuntu Edition** I can see animated gif's with *Navigator* (the default one). But on **bq Aquaris E4.5 Ubuntu Edition** when I press on an animated gif, *Navigator* asks for an app to choose. *[Gallery](https://uappexplorer.com/app/com.ubuntu.gallery)* and *[Image Viewer](https://uappexplorer.com/app/imageviewer.mhall119)* can open it, but it is not animated.

Does anybody know how to view them?